# Lifecycle callbacks not working

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I'm currently trying out Symfony 4, but I am having some problems with events triggered by database action (prePersist, preUpdate...)

With Symfony 3, I used to use EntityListener to accomplish this, but I found them really convoluted in Symfony 4 documentation. But I also discovered the LifecycleCallbacks, that I used like this:

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PostRepository")
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
*/
class Post
{
     //Attributes and other functions not included for the sake of clarity, but if I use them, consider that they exist
     /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */ 
    public function setPostSlug()
    {
         $title = $this->getPostTitle();
         $title = strtolower($title);

         $keywords = preg_split("/[\s,']+/", $title);
         $slug = implode('-', $keywords);

         dump($slug);

         $this->$slug = $slug;

         return $this;
     }
}
```

My post are created through a Symfony form, and before persistence, I want to break down the title I gave to my post in a standardized string that I will use in my URLs to access said post. Unfortunately, the event never trigger on persistence, despite the slug being generated correctly. I tried to do the operation both on prePersist and postPersist events, but none worked. I searched the issue, and saw that LifecycleCallbacks needed a cache clear to be taken into account, but doing so didn't help.

Here is the action responsible for the post creation, if that might help:

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/create/post", name="admin-create-post")
 * @param Request $request
 */
public function createPost(Request $request)
{
    $post = new Post();

    $form = $this->createForm(PostType::class, $post);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $post = $form->getData();
        $em->persist($post);
        $em->flush();
        $this->redirectToRoute('main');
    }

    return $this->render('admin/new_post.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

Would you know the source of the problem, or which other tools I could use to obtain the desired result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should work in the same way, do You have entity definitions in annotations or in yaml/xml?

Comment: @kuba_ceg I manage everything using annotations, as you can see at the top of the post class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handle complex Lifecycle with EventListener
for this .. do :

```
# services.yml

AppBundle\EventListener\YourListener:
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }

// YourListener.php
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

class YourListener {
     /**
      * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
      */
      public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args): void
      {
          $post = $args->getEntity();

          if ($post instanceof Post) {
             // Do your job
          }
      }
}
```

But I use symfony EventListenerSubscriber Like this:

```
    /**
 * This needs to be set through passed argument in case of accident duplicate
 *
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 */
public function setTrackingNumber()
{
    $this->trackingNumber = NumberCreator::randomStringWithNDigits(self::TRACKING_DIGIT_COUNT);
}
```

so I think you need do that in your slug setter like this

```
 /**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */ 
public function setSlug()
{
     $title = $this->getPostTitle();
     $title = strtolower($title);

     $keywords = preg_split("/[\s,']+/", $title);
     $slug = implode('-', $keywords);

     dump($slug);

     $this->$slug = $slug;

     return $this;
 }
```

I think method name is issue ... I hope this is help to you

Comment: Ok, I'll try it out, but what about the EventListenerSubscriber used in the Symfony Documentation? Is it useless?

Comment: @Meleadeles no , of course not , I edit answer, look at that.

Comment: @Meleadeles but keep attention to this issue, I think after persist in first time this is work ... and when you want to update your post with new title ... slug like previous title, I'm not sure but I think.

Comment: Ok, the method name effectively seemed to be the issue, I changed it to createSlug, and reintroduced the normal setter, and it worked fine. Thanks.